# EC2 : Rails deployment gives blank pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my rails application on EC2. It runs on two servers. One for rails application and second for DB.

When I start application using "rails s -e production&" and if I stay connected using SSH, 
I can see the webpages.

As soon as I disconnect SSH I can not see the pages.

There are no errors thrown. One weird thing is "Production.log" file does not have anything.
everything is spit out on console.

Answer (score 0):

You are running rails in the current ssh session. Any programs you have running during that session will stop if you disconnect. You need to set up your rails app to run as a daemon using something like Phusion Passenger.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically running the built in [WEBrick](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/index.html) server that is not really meant for production so it's likely that the process is getting killed after the parent process (your ssh process) gets terminated.

You can probably tweak the configuration to make [WEBrick](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/index.html) not quit, or you can simply run your session using [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)

**Screen:**

```
$ screen
$ rails s -e production &
$ screen -d
```

When you want to reattach:

```
$ screen -r
```

**Tmux:**

```
$ tmux
$ rails s -e production &
$ # Hit <ctrl-b><ctrl-d> to detach
```

When you want to reattach:

```
$ screen attach -t 0
```

Or like @datasage mentioned you can run your Rails with an actual production web server like  [Passenger Phusion](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) or [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/).